# jQuery plugin to continually horizontally scroll on mouseover

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Using this [site](http://munnrabot.com/projects.html) as a reference. Trying to mimic this effect using JavaScript, hover over the right or left sides of the images and see that it continually scrolls. Is there a jQuery plugin that handles this? Preferably one that is customizable and extendable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for jQuery plugin (or code) to automatically scroll Carousel items on mousover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464187/looking-for-jquery-plugin-or-code-to-automatically-scroll-carousel-items-on-mou)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JMyCarousel](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jMyCarousel) jQuery plugin.
Although [this](http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/) is probably closer to what you want

Answer (score 2):

This script is also a champ, documentation is fairly thorough: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/#quickdemo

Cheers.