# How to scroll when cursor is on the edge of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div(menubar) that has a lot of links and these links are out of the view. I must make the div scroll to the right or left when the cursor is at the edge of the menu div, in order to bring these menu items into the view. 
[image]

I am a beginner with Jquery, so any help is greatly appreciated.

[Markup is in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftaran/y9a64/10/)

Comment: Did you try searching first? this question is asked here on daily basis.

Comment: yes I have, Ive found a couple examples but there arent any working solutions.

Comment: @xerxes did solutions proposed by me help to solve your problem?

Comment: Ive had a look and they seem to be helpful,thanks for posting, but am writing unit tests now so will have to work on this problem tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short:**

Use-ready solutions:

- [Scrolling-carousel](http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/)
- [Jmycarousel](http://www.khazar.com/academics/portal/canada/2011spring/mart369/javascript/jmycarousel.htm) ([demo](http://www.enova-tech.net/lab/jMyCarousel/))
- [Smooth div scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/#quickdemo)

**Full** answers you can read on relative questions:

- [jQuery plugin to continually horizontally scroll on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400053/jquery-plugin-to-continually-horizontally-scroll-on-mouseover)
- [Looking for jQuery plugin (or code) to automatically scroll Carousel items on mousover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464187/looking-for-jquery-plugin-or-code-to-automatically-scroll-carousel-items-on-mo)

Comment: The disavantage in basing your answer on third party links is that 8 years later almost none works or have the content that had at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example, in this example you can see how they scroll the div when the mouse  at right edge of the div. you can do the same thing.

[How to Auto Scroll a div on mouse move over the margins?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-auto-scroll-a-div-on-mouse-move-over-the-margins/)

Comment: hi, i was wondering if you could help me with creating a dashboard layout using jquery. what i have in mind is similar to the dashboard demonstrated in https://beebole-apps.com/.

Comment: What help you need ? what you did so far?

Comment: @BalaKrishnan웃 Link broken

Answer (score -3):

Here Answer

```
<div onmouseover="this.className='addscrool'"    onmouseout="this.className='removescrool';" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px  solid Blue">
 </div>
 <style>
.addscrool
{
overflow-y: scroll;
}   .removescrool
{
overflow-y:hidden ;
 }
```